# Outlook Add-in - How to get Outlook email item Sensitivity using Microsoft tools

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an `Outlook Add-in` using TypeScript Angular. I have observed a difference between Outlook add-ins behavior i.e. while opening sensitive mails, add-ins `disabled` automatically in `MAC` but in `Windows` still able to access.

`Outlook Add-in disabled on MAC`
[image: Add-ins disabled automatically while open sensitive mails]

`Outlook Add-in enabled on Windows`
[image: [Add-in enabled on Windows] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoWwu.png)]

Environment: `Outlook on Windows` vs `Outlook on Mac`

I have gone through [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview?view=excel-js-preview) but still unable to get sufficient information related to mail sensitivity.

I have tried installing preview version but when I do `forward/reply all` with existing sensitive email I am not getting the sensitivity information.

Below is my `code snippet:`

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.sensitivity.getAsync(function(asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    console.log("Sensitivity: " + asyncResult.value);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to get sensitivity: " + 
    JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
  }
});
```

`Note:` The above code snippet will work only for Appointment as per the document.

`Expected:`
I have to disable few actions in my Outlook add-in when we are opening `sensitive` mails. Can you please suggest how to achieve sensitive mail information through any tool.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview?view=excel-js-preview#sensitivity) property is available on Windows (for the Microsoft 365 subscription) only in the [Outlook add-in API preview requirement set](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview?view=excel-js-preview).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this property will be available only for appointment in Compose mode but I need the sensitive information for New compose mail and appointment aswell.

Comment: You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.